# Is there any software that takes set builder notations and returns roster notations?

Tags: math, language-features, set-theory

For example, if you feed {x|xεZ,0<x} to it, 
it returns { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,...}

Comment: Do you want it to return an infinite set ?  What you actually seem to want, from your example, is to transform what you call set builder notation into what I'll call 'set exemplar' notation because I don't know whether it has a more widely used name.  Please clarify your requirements.

Comment: Sorry for the late response I didn't notice that I got a reply, and thank you for your comment. What I meant was not a literal infinite set. I want it to return an abbreviated set, just like the above example. If a given set builder notation is infinite, I want it to return abbreviated 'set exemplar' notation like { 1,2,3,4,...}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any such software.

Note that no general algorithm for enumerating arbitrary sets can exist; a program that accepts *any* set written in set-builder notation must also be able to solve e.g. the halting problem. Moreover there exist sets that cannot be enumerated even theoretically, for example those whose construction requires use of a choice function on the reals.

Naturally the problem is easier if you restrict what kind of expressions can appear in the set-builder notation, but even then anything more complex than linear inequalities is surprisingly hard. For instance, it is known that no algorithm exists to determine whether or not a polynomial equality `P(x_1, ..., x_9)=0` in nine variables has an integer solution (this is an extension of Hilbert's 10th problem), never mind actually finding some exemplar solutions.